# Flutter REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission problem

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-play-console, pub.dev

When I want to update an application, I get this warning from google play. I have attached my `AndroidManifest.xml` file and my `pubspec.yaml` file.
[image: Play console mail]

I researched this error and found out that the open_file library uses this permission automatically. Even though I deleted this library, I still get this warning in the play console when I send an update.
[image]

[image: My AndroidManifest file]

Comment: May be some other plugin is using the permission. Have you check every thing?

Comment: I didn't check them all. I just found out that open_file uses it. As you said, one of the other libraries may also be using this permission, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: do you found the solution

Comment: Unfortunately. I still haven't found a solution and can't release an update.

Comment: Have you tried to contact Google Play policy support team ? They provide link (to contact support) in the email that you receive when the app update is rejected.

Comment: This is how I got a response;
"We apologize for the inconvenience, but our team cannot respond with issues related to policy sent at this time, so please contact our policy support team through your Play Console."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by updating the channels in closed test.

Comment: Can you add more details, I'm facing this problem as well. How does one "Update the channels" in closed test? @safauludogan

Comment: If you have this permission in your last apk without any conditions in closed tests, you should publish a new update on it. You do not have to publish this update you have release.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a pubsec.yaml file containing the **open_file** package, you may receive such a reject message from the Google Play Store.

You can use the **open_file_safe** package instead.

> https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_safe

Comment: I used all the libraries listed below, including this library, and was rejected again.
1: open_file 
2: open_filex
3: open_file_safe 
4: better_open_file